# Magento 2.3 - Newsletter questions

Tags: magento2.3, newsletter

Good day,
im currently working on our Newsletter templates but it seems like im unable to actually work with HTML there. I tried writing a full on html file in there but upon saving the template it strips the `<html>` tags. So tried without the `<html>` tag and just putting my content in there with various divs and stuff. I used the `Template Styles` section to style them but those wont get applied.

Is there a guide out on how to create Newsletter Templates or how to do stuff there in general? Im completly lost...

Comment: A quick google brings up the [magento developer documentation](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/guide/templates/email/) which should have everything you need in order to change newsletter templates